# How to scroll inner div but show scrollbar on outer div

Tags: html, css, layout, scroll

I am getting a funny situation.
[image: Layout]
There is a container which can be scrolled as shown as (3) in picture.
This container encloses many rows in it which basically have two `divs` each.
First `div` (1) contains a very long title which can go beyond its width and second `div` (2) contains small text.

What I need is that I don't want scrollbar on title `div` but I want to scroll title `divs` which contain long content on scrolling from outer container. How can I do it?

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzjObY)

Please ask me in comments if you want me to describe it more clearly.

Comment: You want the outer scroll to scroll only the title divs and keep the (2) div where they are? Also can you share your code using jsfiddle or codepen please?

Comment: `::-webkit-scrollbar` for webkit browsers, `-moz-scrollbar` for FF.

Comment: @NasirT Yes, and sorry I didn't save any code when I was trying to achieve the layout I want